# Delay implementation in PSpice

Tags: spice, delay, pspice, modeling

1.I have been using oscillator circuit as Parametric delay block with the 
   help of other sub blocks at the output/around.

[image: OSCILLATOR]

2. Second method is RC for the delay at the output of any circuit (ABM) or 
   comparator 
   -Example Netlist

`.SUBCKT COMPARATOR IN+ IN- OUT PARAMS: DELAY=1n
E_1 OUT_int 0 VALUE= {IF(V(IN+) > V(IN-), 5, 0)}
R_1 OUT_int OUT 1
C_1 OUT 0 {DELAY /(0.693)}
.ENDS COMPARATOR`

But the second method does not provide accurate delay and it gives exponential behaviour.

Is there any better way of implementing Parametric delay circuit in modeling point of in PSpice/ltspice?

Comment: PSpice should have behavioural expressions, so maybe there is something similar to LTspice's `delay()`. If not, and what you want is a simple delay, use the transmission line. That will work every time.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen i am new to modeling can you please provide me link or insights on transmission line delay? / Can it be used for parametric delay in digital circuits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LTspice, the lossless `tline` (or the lossy `ltline`) can be used to form a parametric delay (see example below). PSpice should have something very similar. Search the net for a certain `PSPCREF.PDF`, which is the manual for PSpice, holding details about circuit elements, their usage, and more.

However, your comment mentions a *digital* delay, which changes the problem. In LTspice you can use the builtin A-devices (in `[Digital]`) which makes use of the `td` parameter, while in PSpice you have their builtin logical gates with some similarly-functional parameter (I'll leave it up to you to find out what, I don't use PSpice).

Below is th example showing the analog delay with `tline` (`V(analog)`), and the digital version, built with a simple buffer, `[Digital]/buf1` (`V(digital)`):

[image: test]

You can also use the behavioural expression `delay()`, or `absdelay()`, but I recommend these two over the expression, unless you need a time-variable delay.